# Does the 10309 Succulents set contain only non-unique bricks?

Tags: piece-information

First-time poster here: I write on innovation topics, have been Lego-infatuated for maybe 45 years now. My kid and I were assembling the 2022 succulents kit (#10309) and I noticed a piece that looked like a Robin Hood-type hat. Turns out it was (Forestman hat - 6395137). I've since disposed of the box but I distinctly remember it saying somewhere that no net-new pieces were developed for that set. Can anyone confirm this? It's the jumping-off point for a post on compositional innovation.

Comment: If the claim of no new pieces isn't actually on the box, maybe it was in a video you watched about the set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see anything on the box indicating that there are no new parts in this set:

[image: box front]

[image: box back]

I also briefly flipped through the instructions and didn't see a mention of this. However, I do not believe that there were any new molds created for this set. We can see this by looking through the [Rebrickable inventory](https://rebrickable.com/sets/10309-1/succulents/?inventory=1#parts).

While it does not appear to me that any new molds were made for this set, there were several recolors. For example, both of these elements appeared for the first time in this set:

[43898 in Bright Light Orange](https://rebrickable.com/parts/43898/dish-3-x-3-inverted-radar/)

[image: 43898]

[24946 in Yellowish Green](https://rebrickable.com/parts/24946/food-egg-with-15mm-hole-plain/158/)

[image: 24946 in Yellowish Green]

As of May 2023, at least one element has only been used in this set:

[43898 in Coral](https://rebrickable.com/parts/43898/dish-3-x-3-inverted-radar/1050/)

[image: 43898 in Coral]

This set could still support your thesis. Injecting a new color of plastic into an existing mold is much cheaper and more economically efficient than machining a new mold, and demonstrates the sort of compositional innovation you are discussing.

Comment: https://brickflips.com/10309-succulents-botanical-collection-review/ has a more complete list of new colors, but apparently no new molds.

Comment: @jncraton incredibly helpful, thank you! Definitely agree on the mold re-use fitting under compositional. Was thinking of the Apollo 13 'square peg round hole' scene as the lead-in example for the piece. Really appreciate your taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: @Karsten Happy to help! Good luck on your post.

Comment: @jncraton it's coming together! If you're interested, I can send you a link when it's out. Posting to LinkedIn, if you're on that I'd be happy to credit you for your help.